# Was Aziz actually Yusuf's uncle?

Tags: abdulrazak-gurnah, paradise

Khalil repeatedly tells Yusuf that Aziz is not, in fact, his Uncle, but Yusuf persists in referring to him as such, and the book itself seems to refer to him as his Uncle. For example,

> In Uncle Aziz's absence Khalil was less interested in the shop.

And

> In the absence of [Yusuf's] uncle he stepped beyond the wall and found that the garden was divided into quarters, with a pool in the center...

Was Aziz really Yusuf's uncle?